# How to Restrict the view of a user to a select list of Accounts

Tags: permissions, list-view

I have a requirement where in i want a user with particular profile need to see only one view(Not all views)  when we click on Account tab in salesforce. Is it possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be possible using a visualforce tab to replace your standard/custom object tab to return either a  [specific list view](http://blog.deliveredinnovation.com/2010/06/01/create-visualforce-tab-to-display-static-list-view-for-standard-or-custom-object/) (instead of recently viewed records) or to return only a specific set of available list views per profile.

Answer (score 3):

In order to restrict them, you would take the following steps:

1. Remove "Create and Customize List Views" (profile)
2. Remove "Run Reports" (profile)
3. Remove all search bars
4. Remove all API access
5. Edit all list views so they are explicitly excluded, except for the one(s) you want

Note that this is still not guaranteed to keep them from snooping around and seeing accounts they shouldn't see. The only foolproof way of this is to restrict them by sharing; you must first set the sharing model to private, then create sharing rules so they can see just the accounts you would like them to see (and other rules so everyone else can see what they should see).